# Java Generics: (extends List<E>) vs (extends List)

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, bounded-types

Assume I want to declare an interface named `A` which extends class `List`.
What is the difference if I write as
`A<E> extends List`
or
`A<E> extends List<E>`
?
What is the difference between objects instantiated form these two classes?

The question remains about methods or classes with bounded type parameters. like

`public <T extends aClass<T>> void methodName(T t)`

and

`public <T extends aClass> void methodName(T t)`
.

---

CLARIFICATION:

I know what is raw type.
Suppose we have this:

`Class someClass<E> extends ArrayList`

`someClass` is subclass of `ArrayList`, means it inherits all accessible fields and methods of `ArrayList`.

I know if I replace `ArrayList` with `ArrayList<E>`, if I invoke `someClass<String> object` it would pass `String` to the super class which is `ArrayList` and that's fine.

But let's stick with the code. Now if i invoke `someClass<String> object`, it doesn't pass `String` to the `ArrayList`. So now, object is `raw` or not and how its fields and methods work?

Answer (score 0):

```
A<E> extends List
```

should never be used, since `List` is a raw type.

You should either use:

```
interface A<E> extends List<E>
```

if `A` should be a `List` of some generic element type.

or:

```
interface A extends List<String> // or any concrete type instead of String
```

if `A` should be a `List` of a specific element type.